# How to .join() in React if array doesn't exist initially

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a functional react component that displays information after an api request. Initially the object it displays is blank, since the request hasn't been made. In the object is an array that looks like this:

```
['US', 'USA', 'United States of America']
```

When I simply display the array, after the api request, it displays it as a single string on the page with no spaces between ex:

```
USUSAUnited States of America
```

Naturally, I want to format it with .join(', ' ) to format the string like US, USA, United States of America, but after I add the .join(', '), it throws an error:

```
TypeError: props.modalCountry.alt_spellings is undefined
```

It seems like .join() is trying to run on first render before there is an actual modalCountry object. How do I get this method to not run until the object & array actually exists?

Comment: We will probably need a bit more of your code to figure this one out. We can't see any of what you are actually doing.

Comment: @CalebH. My code is literally a functional react component returning {props.modalCountry.alt_spellings} but breaking with {props.modalCountry.alt_spellings.join(', ')}

Comment: Yes, but how are you getting the alt_spellings loaded?

Comment: As Ori Drori explained, you can do the check within the functional component itself to ensure you're not calling functions on undefined objects, or you could do a little data sanitation on your response data in the parent component to ensure you're at least passing an array.  You can also even still use PropTypes on functional components to also ensure you're not calling array functions (i.e. `join`) on non-array objects, which would fail equally as badly or worse.

Comment: is modalCountry from a redux store? why don't you set a default empty array

Comment: @Dominic modalCountry is from the store, but it's an object. I may go with setting modalCountry.alt_spellings to an empty array if I don't like short circuit evaluation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In React - [Booleans, Null, and Undefined Are Ignored](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored), so you can return `null` or `undefined` if the array doesn't exist. Another option is to supply a default array.

Option 1 - Use [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) to skip the `array.join()`, if the array doesn't exist yet:

```
const Component = ({ arr = [] }) => (
    <div>
        {arr && arr.join()}
    </div>
);
```

Option 2 - Render `null` if no array:

```
const Component = ({ arr = [] }) => (
    <div>
        {arr ? arr.join() : null}
    </div>
);
```

Option 3 - Supply a default array as value:

```
const Component = ({ arr = [] }) => (
    <div>
        {arr.join()}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: There isn't a more elegant solution? That seems rather hacky

Comment: These are simple solutions to a simple problem. However, the future is [React suspense](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-suspense-1c73b4b0b1e6).

Comment: There is nothing hacky about it, peter. You have a variable that is not initialized. You somehow need to work around this.

Comment: @OriDrori short circuit evaluation is the best, but It's unfortunate because this component will never be accessed without the array.